# Symbol.toPrimitive vs Object.prototype.valueOf

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 6, a new `Symbol.toPrimitive` symbol is introduced, which, when used as an object key, [should define](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) a function to return the *primitive value* of an object:

```
let object = {
    aNumber: 0,
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
        return this.aNumber;
    }
};

object.aNumber = 5;
console.log(object + 2) // 7
```

However, there is also the `Object.prototype.valueOf` function, which, [according to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), could be redefined to convert an object to the primitive value:

```
let object = {
    aNumber: 0,
    valueOf() {
        return this.aNumber;
    }
};

object.aNumber = 5;
console.log(object + 2) // 7
```

So, which of these ways to convert an object to its primitive value should be used in ES6 when defining a new object?

Comment: [Spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-toprimitive) -> _The abstract operation ToPrimitive takes an input argument and an optional argument PreferredType. The abstract operation ToPrimitive converts its input argument to a non-Object type. If an object is capable of converting to more than one primitive type, it may use the optional hint PreferredType to favour that type._ - If there is no custom `.toPrimitive()` the reesult of `.valueOf()` is returned

Comment: @Andreas The paragraph you linked to is related not to `Symbol` specification, but to converting _any_ non-primitive value to primitive one. The according spec for 'Symbol.toPrimitive' is [in the paragraph 19.4.3.4.](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-symbol.prototype-@@toprimitive)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main purpose of `Symbol.toPrimitive` is to change the order in which `toString` and `valueOf` are called in different coercion scenarios.

An example of this is the `Date` native object, where it will convert the value to a string instead of a number by default:

```
console.log(1 + new Date()); // "1Mon Aug 15 2016 13:25:31 GMT-0500 (EST)"

var a = new Date(1000);
console.log(a == 1000); // false
console.log(a == a.toString()); // true
```

If you do not intend to do this, **you should just override both `obj.valueOf` and `obj.toString`** to match the behaviour that you want -- this is what most of the native objects do in JavaScript.

Note that both `valueOf` **and** `toString` should be overridden, as the [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation may call either of them for coercion depending on the reason ToPrimitive is being called.

Comment: `Symbol` is now supported in all modern browsers (sans IE11), and `Symbol.toPrimitive` is [currently supported by Chrome, Firefox, and Node](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-well-known_symbols_Symbol.toPrimitive).

Comment: @rvighne Thanks for the reminder, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also `Symbol.toPrimitive` is called with one argument that indicate which type it should be converted to ("default". "number" or "string")